# How get distinct list of values and below that all the documents that are of that distinct value?

Tags: mongodb

Getting my head around MongoDB document design and trying to figure out how to do something or if I'm barking up the wrong tree.

I'm creating a mini CMS. The site will contains either documents or url's that are grouped by a category, i.e. There's a group called 'shop' that has a list of links to items on another site and there's a category called 'art' that has a list of works of art, each of which has a title, summary and images for a slideshow.

So one possible way to do this would be to have a collection that would look something like:

```
[{category: 'Products',
  title: 'Thong',
  href: 'http://www.thongs.com'
},{
  category: 'Products',
  title: 'Incredible Sulk',
  href:'http://www.sulk.com'
},{
  category: 'Art',
  title: 'Cool art',
  summary: 'This is a summary to display',
  images: [...]
}]
```

But, and here's the question.... when I'm building the webpage this structure isn't much use to me. the homepage contains lists of 'things' grouped by their category, lists... menus.. stuff like that. To be able to easily do that I need to have something that looks more like:

```
[
 {'Products':[
      {title:'thong', href:'http://www.thongs.com'},
      {title:'Incredible Sulk'}
  ]
 },
 {'Art':[
      {title:'Cool art',summary:'This is a summary to display',images:[...]}
  ]
 }
]
```

So the question is, can I somehow do this transformation in MondoDB? If I can't then is it bad to do this in my app server layer(I'd get a grouped list of unique categories and then loop through them querying Mongo for documents of that category)? I'm guessing app server layer is bad, after all mongodb has it all in memory if I'm lucky. If neither of these are good then am I doing it all wrong and should I actually store the structure like this in the first place?

I need to make it easy for the user to create categories on the fly and consider what happens if they start to add lots of documents and I either need to restrict how many documents I pull back for each category or somehow limit the fields returned so that when I query mongodb it doesn't return back a relatively big chunk of data which is slow and wasteful, but instead returns back the minimum I need to create the desired page.

Answer (score 0):

I figured a group query that will give me almost the structure I want, but good enough to use for templates.

```
db.things.group({
    key:{category:true},
    initial:{articles:[]},
    reduce: function(doc, aggregator) {
        aggregator.articles.push(doc);
    }
})
```